# Delete data in the browser

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I can delete data from the application information, you want to permanently delete the data when the application was terminated. However, the data can not be removed completely. Do you know what the problem is from this source?

```
Context context = getBaseContext();
WebView webview = new WebView(context);

deleteCacheDir(this);
clearApplicationCache(null);

CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();

String[] fileList = this.fileList();
    for(String file: fileList) { 
    this.deleteFile(file);
}
WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this).clearUsernamePassword();
WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this).clearHttpAuthUsernamePassword();

webview.clearSslPreferences();
webview.clearView();

webview.clearFormData();
webview.clearHistory();
webview.clearCache(true);
webview.clearMatches();

context.deleteDatabase("/data/data/android.Packege/databaseswebview.db"
context.deleteDatabase("/data/data/android.Packege/databases/webviewCache.db");

webview.freeMemory();

android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
return true;
}
return true;
}
private void clearApplicationCache(java.io.File dir){
if(dir==null)
    dir = getCacheDir();
else;
    if(dir==null)
    return;
else;
    java.io.File[] children = dir.listFiles();
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<children.length;i++)
        if(children[i].isDirectory())
        clearApplicationCache(children[i]);
        else children[i].delete();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
void deleteCacheDir(Context context) {
    Runtime localRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    String cachePath = context.getCacheDir().getPath();
    String cmd = "rm -R " + cachePath;
    try {
        localRuntime.exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you typed `android.Packege` instead of `android.Package` ?

Comment: Oh sorry.Misspelled.When the remaining data is still android.Package.

Comment: Yes, and running. I might but remains at or KB. Removed from the data, not information, want to be automatically 0KB.

Comment: Although the program is moving, will sometimes be remained by data.